# Join table for a subset of the children of table associated with a many-to-many join

Tags: database-design

I have a standard join table for a many-to-many relationship, whose Primary Key is a composite key of two fields. The two fields are the ID from each of the joined tables.

One of the joined tables has-many-children in another table. A standard one-to-many relationship.

That's all fine. But now I want to specify a subset of these children and associate them with the table on the far side of the many-to-many relationship. To be specific:

---

Table: **RaceCourses**
PK: **ID**

Table: **Stables**
PK: **ID**

Table: **StablesToRaceCourses**
PK is a composite key of two foreign keys:
    **RaceCourseID** and
    **StableID**

Table: **Horses**
PK: **ID**
FK: **StableID**

---

That's all fine - a Horse belongs to a single Stable, a RaceCourse has access to a number of stables. But the hard part: each RaceCourse can select a subset of the horses from a stable to which it has access. So ideally this new table would only allow Horses to be associated with a RaceCourse where that RaceCourse is already linked to the Horse's stable.

Something like:

Table: **HorsesForRaceCourses**
FK: **RaceCourseID** links to StablesToRaceCourses.RaceCourseID
FK: **StableID** links to StablesToRaceCourses.StableID
FK: **HorseID** links to Horses.ID
where the PK is a composite of the 3 foreign keys. Does this seem reasonable? I'm using MS Access but it won't enforce referential integrity for me, saying "No unique index found for the referenced field of the primary table". I can get this to work by removing StableID from this table (and linking directly to RaceCourse), but then I need to rely on application logic to ensure a RaceCourse is not associated with a Horse unless the RaceCourse is already associated with that Horse's Stable. Maybe I'm asking too much of the database to enforce this for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a very good question.

There are very, very good reasons to have a database enforce as many relationships as it can. But there are limits to the declaritive nature of databases. Say you have an employee table and a orgunit table. An Orgunit can have many employees but at most one that also has the type of supervisor. Not the simplest thing in the world to do declaratively.

What you are describing is something called an "Association" in conceptual terms. Think of videos, a store, and customers. <-- OMG that's so 1990's. A Store has many movies. A store has many customers. At some point a "rental occurs where customer A, rents movie B from store C. The rental table has all three PK's. That rental table also has a date, and due date, fee paid, etc.

From the PowerDesigner Documents

> In the Merise modeling methodology an association is used to connect several entities that each represents clearly defined objects, but are linked by an event, which may not be so clearly represented by another entity.

In your case the "Selection" is that event. "RaceCourse can select"

In the video rental example, there's probably an association between customer and store and only customers who "belong" to that store can rent there, maybe. That fact doesn't change my rental table.

OK, so this isn't a precise analog to your case but you get the point.

From a pure modeling standpoint you've got stables which own multiple horses, you've got race tracks which work with multiple stables and stables work for many race tracks. That's the end of the third normal stuff.

Now you've got a process called selection. If I were you, I'd model this more as a star schema.

I would put all three keys in addition to the "facts". date selected, date selection starts, date selection ends, contract #, date stable was notified, etc. This will make it very easy to create reports about what horse when where on what date, etc... and if a horse ever changes stables that information will be reflected since you're including the FK for the Stable and not relying on joining to find it.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this every which way in Access and I'm convinced that "compound foreign keys" don't work in Access the way they do in SQL Server.  You can set them up, they just don't work in this case.  I can't find an actual source on this, but after researching problems in database where I have attempted this approach, I've read many forum posts that indicate the old hats know to avoid this.

Instead of using a compound primary key on any table that may need to be referenced by a foreign key, use an single-field Autonumber primary key, typically called ID.  But additionally add a multi-field unique index on the foreign key fields that *would* have been your PK.

This is functionally equivalent, although it sometimes means you need to join in more tables in queries to get the "real" foreign keys.